# How do i add data from jTextfield into jTable? i dont know why i fail. please take a look

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

so i followed a video of making a cash register for groceries on youtube. i followed it step by step, carefully. but when it comes to getText into the jTable1 row, like, when i pressed jButton1 it doesnt work as the video shows.

so, i copied the script to my project out of desperation to see if it works, but it doesnt. then when i tried it on the original file with original project. it works. so try to copy all of it. in its entirety to my project. there's no difference in the coding, and the variables, and the buttons that's been declared or whatever it is called in english.
still doesnt works.

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
 Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
 package kasiraldo;
 import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE;
 import java.util.Vector;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
//import javax.swing.JTable;
/**
*
* @author AldoFerino
*/
public class kasirJframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form kasirJframe
 */
public kasirJframe() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Nama = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Harga = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Qty = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Jumlah = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    Pesan = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Totalharga = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Bayar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Kembalian = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Nama");

    Nama.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            NamaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Harga");

    Harga.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            HargaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    Harga.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            HargaKeyPressed(evt);
        }
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            HargaKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setText("Qty");

    Qty.setText(" ");
    Qty.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            QtyActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    Qty.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            QtyKeyPressed(evt);
        }
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            QtyKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Input");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Jumlah.setText("0");

    jTable1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Nama", "Harga", "Qty", "Jumlah"
        }
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jTable1.setAutoscrolls(false);
    jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    jTable1.setOpaque(false);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

    Pesan.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

    Totalharga.setText("Rp.");

    Bayar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BayarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    Bayar.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            BayarKeyPressed(evt);
        }
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            BayarKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Bayar");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Kembalian.setText("Rp.");

    jButton2.setText("Delete");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(61, 61, 61)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(Nama)
                        .addComponent(Harga, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(Qty, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 151, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                        .addComponent(Jumlah, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(Kembalian, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(Bayar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Totalharga, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(Pesan, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 365, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(Nama, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(Harga, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(Jumlah, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(Qty, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(Pesan, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(Totalharga, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(Bayar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addComponent(Kembalian, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void BayarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                     

private void NamaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                    

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Tombol Input untuk masukkan data yang di input oleh user ke tabel
    Pesan.setText("");
    DefaultTableModel a = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    if(Nama.getText().trim().equals("")){
        Pesan.setText("MAAF, NAMA BARANG HARUS DI ISI");
    }else{
        int c = Integer.parseInt(Harga.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(Qty.getText());
        int d = b * c;
        Jumlah.setText(""+d);
        Jumlah.setVisible(false);
        int t = 0;
        Vector z = new Vector();
        z.add(Nama.getText());
        z.add("Rp.".concat(Harga.getText()));
        z.add(Qty.getText());
        z.add("Rp.".concat(Jumlah.getText()));
        a.addRow(z);
        for(int e = 0; e <a.getRowCount(); e++){
            t += Integer.parseInt(a.getValueAt(e, 3).toString().substring(3));
        }
        Totalharga.setText("Rp."+t);
        Nama.setText("");
        Harga.setText("");
        Qty.setText("");
    }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Hapus
    //DefaultTableModel a = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel a = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    int select = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    a.removeRow(select);
    Nama.setText("");
    Harga.setText("");
    Qty.setText("");
    int t= 0;
    for(int e = 0; e <a.getRowCount(); e++){
        t += Integer.parseInt(a.getValueAt(e, 3).toString().substring(3));
    }
    Totalharga.setText("Rp."+t);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(Totalharga.getText().substring(3));
    int f = Integer.parseInt(Bayar.getText());
    int h = f - g;
    Kembalian.setText("Rp."+h);
}                                        

private void BayarKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               
    // tertekan di kolom bayar
    Pesan.setText("");
    char a = evt.getKeyChar();
    int  b = evt.getKeyCode() ;
    if(!Character.isDigit(a)){
        evt.consume();
        Pesan.setText("maaf hanya bisa input pakai angka");
    } else if (b == VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        evt.consume();
        Pesan.setText("maaf hanya bisa input pakai angka");
    }
}                              

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int g = Integer.parseInt(Totalharga.getText().substring(3));
    int f = Integer.parseInt(Bayar.getText());
    int h = f - g;
    Kembalian.setText("Rp."+h);
}                                        

private void QtyKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                             
    // Qty terketik
    Pesan.setText("");
    char a = evt.getKeyChar();
    int  b = evt.getKeyCode() ;
    if(!Character.isDigit(a)){
        evt.consume();
        Pesan.setText("maaf hanya bisa input pakai angka");
    } else if (b == VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        evt.consume();
        Pesan.setText("maaf hanya bisa input pakai angka");
    }
}                            

private void HargaKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Pesan.setText("");
    char a = evt.getKeyChar();
    int  b = evt.getKeyCode() ;
    if(!Character.isDigit(a)){
        evt.consume();
        Pesan.setText("maaf hanya bisa input pakai angka");
    } else if (b == VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        evt.consume();
        Pesan.setText("maaf hanya bisa input pakai angka");
    }
}                              

private void BayarKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                

private void HargaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                     

private void HargaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                

private void QtyKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                              

private void QtyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(kasirJframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new kasirJframe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField Bayar;
private javax.swing.JTextField Harga;
private javax.swing.JLabel Jumlah;
private javax.swing.JLabel Kembalian;
private javax.swing.JTextField Nama;
private javax.swing.JLabel Pesan;
private javax.swing.JTextField Qty;
private javax.swing.JLabel Totalharga;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration                   
void isVisible(boolean b) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To 
change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

and instead giving me this error in the output window tab when i pressed jButton1 or button "Input" in the user interface window or jframe or design.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at kasiraldo.kasirJframe.jButton1ActionPerformed(kasirJframe.java:264)
at kasiraldo.kasirJframe.access$700(kasirJframe.java:15)
at kasiraldo.kasirJframe$6.actionPerformed(kasirJframe.java:97)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
```

sorry if my question looks so vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the default value of your `Qty` text field to `" "`(one space).

```
Qty.setText(" ");
```

And you might be adding 1 to that text field and pressing the submit button which triggers `jButton1ActionPerformed` method. You are trying to parse text `" 1"` into the integer here which is causing `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"` exception -

```
int b = Integer.parseInt(Qty.getText());
```

The simple solution would be set `""` (blank) into the `Qty` text field -

```
Qty.setText("");
```

It should work just fine.

Comment: THANK YOU! turns out that in jTextfield of Qty has space in it. i deleted it just like you guys said and it worked! just because of a space.... i feel stupid now. but anyway, THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"
```

Actually, this says it all: `"1"` can be parsed into a number, but with the space added to it, `" 1"`, this is a plain text `String`, not a numeric format anymore.

call `trim()` on the `String` you are trying to parse, to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: THANK YOU! turns out that in jTextfield of Qty has space in it. i deleted it just like you guys said and it worked! just because of a space.... i feel stupid now. but anyway, THANKS!!